# why this mysql code have error?

Tags: mysql, sql

i see errors when use this mysql code why?

```
CREATE TABLE books (
      id int(6) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      title varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
      author varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
      price decimal(3,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) TYPE=MyISAM;

    INSERT INTO books VALUES (1, 'Where God Went Wrong', 'Oolon Colluphid', '24.99');
    INSERT INTO books VALUES (2, 'Some More of God\'s Greatest Mistakes', 'Oolon Colluphid', '17.99');
    INSERT INTO books VALUES (3, 'Who Is This God Person Anyway?', 'Oolon Colluphid', '14.99');
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 7

Comment: The error tells you exactly whats wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ENGINE` instead of `TYPE`. The `TYPE` is long since abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
TYPE=MyISAM;
```

with

```
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

It is not `TYPE` anymore. Use the name `ENGINE` instead:

```
TYPE keyword is depreciated (since 5.0) and not supported in MySQL5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ENGINE` instead of `TYPE`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html